# Searching for a tabbed SSH client with multi-execution support for Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, client

I am using [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) on Windows for an SSH client; but, I want to switch to Ubuntu.

Is there any app you can recommend, that supports:

- A minimum of 12 sessions
- Tabbed sessions
- multi-execution support

I prefer using an open-source solution (free or paid), but would also consider a proprietary software.

Comment: What is multi-execution? Anyway, the regular Terminal supports multiple tabs. (I just checked and confirm that 12 tabs are possible in the same Terminal window.) In Unix-like systems we generally distinguish between the terminal emulator and the SSH client, with the SSH client being of course blissfully unaware of the terminal emulator and its tabs.

Comment: Well, multi-execution is multi-execution. It open all SSH sessions and you can attach or detach each session. Everything you are typing gets into all attached sessions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You may like [Gnome Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.ro/p/introduction.html) which supports managing and simultaneous typing in multiple terminals. See [How do I run the same linux command in more than one tab/shell simultaneously](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89339/how-do-i-run-the-same-linux-command-in-more-than-one-tab-shell-simultaneously).

Comment: Loosk good. Thank you. If anyone else know some other clients, let us know!

Answer (score 7):

The best solution i found by far is [byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu) *(maybe running in your client machine in your situation)*. Its a terminal app based on `tmux` *(also can use screen instead)* and can achieve what you want and has other great features like notifications which make it nearly an imperative for me *(I use it also on my Arch based systems)*.

- You can make splits on the same window, and also make multiple windows.
- Then you can enter a command(s) to all windows *(with `Ctrl`+`F9`)* or splits *(with `Shift`+`F9`)*.
- Handles multiple (de)atachable running sessions *(instances)*.
- Also you can set profiles to start *byobu sessions* with certain config *(splits, windows, commands like ssh...)*.
- Notifications _(updates, reboot required...) and *systray-like "indicators"* (cpu, mem, entropy, wlan strength...).

Check [this post](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/08/learn-byobu-in-10-minutes-while.html) from the father of this great tool *(Dustin Kirkland from Canonical cloud staff)*, with a simple but usefull video tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a native Linux SSH session manager similar to puTTy/SecureCRT, I heartily recommend [PAC Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/).

**Update 20190426:**
As @rince has kindly pointed out, there is now a fork of PAC Manager available on GitHub called [Asbru Connection Manager](https://github.com/asbru-cm/asbru-cm) that is being actively developed. It appears to maintain the same functionality as PAC Manager.

PAC Manager/Asbru is basically a GUI frontend to manage your SSH sessions by name, group, vendor types, device, switch, routers, firewall groups. You can also set up scripting, KeePass integration, etc.

Here is a brief list of some of their features:

- Unique Linux app to implement SecureCRT's functionality (more or less!)
- Remote and local macros
- Remotely send commands with EXPECT regexp
- Cluster connections. Connections on same cluster share keystrokes.
- Scripting support. (vía Perl code)
- Serial/tty connection via cu/tip/remote-tty connections.
- Pre/post connections local executions
- TABS OR WINDOWS for connections.
- Proxy support
- KeePass integration
- Wake On LAN capabilities
- Possibility to split terminals in the same TAB
- Quick access to configured connections via tray menu icon
- Best Linux GUI for ssh, telnet, sftp, rdesktop, vnc, cu, remote-tty, ftp, etc)

The PAC Manager application is available as either a .deb, .rpm, or as a traditional .tar.gz.

Installation instructions can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/files/).

The Asbru Connection Manager application can be installed with the following commands:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/asbru-cm/asbru-cm/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install asbru-cm
```

I'm not sure how active current development on PAC Manager is; but, as a network engineer, I find it useful in environments with a large number of devices.

I have successfully used PAC Manager on Xubuntu 12.04, 16.04, and 18.04.
installations. I've also successfully installed Asbru Connection Manager on 10.04 and it appears to work on 19.04 as well.

Comment: For everyone else, if you're having trouble getting PAC Manager running, there is a fork available at https://github.com/asbru-cm/asbru-cm
I'm using it on Kubuntu 19.04

Comment: @rince Thanks for pointing this out. I with definitely take a look at it. PAC had been getting a bit old. Nice to see someone forking it and continuing to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out PAC Manager. I really enjoy it. 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/

Best SSH client I can find for linux.

Comment: This is broken for Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @liv2hak I'm using on 16.04 just fine. If you are having issues I recommend looking through their bug reports. Others are having same issue with an easy workaround: https://sourceforge.net/p/pacmanager/bugs/search/?q=ubuntu+17.10

Answer (score 0):

An other solution, if You run Gnome, try [Argos extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/)

Just put you ssh command in the `argos.sh`.

for example :

```
echo "SSH"
echo "---"
echo "your_server" | iconName=gnome-terminal bash='ssh user@your_server' terminal=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default Ubuntu terminal supports multiple tab for that you need to change the terminal settings.
Go to Terminal->Preference and select 'Tab' in 'Open new terminals in' Option.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kmbq.png)